# Is there a way to search an Excel column with MM/YY instead of "MM/DD/YYYY"?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to sum the number of times a certain month in a year occurs in a column, and then sum a cost associated with that month. For example, `=SUMIF(J:J,"07/31/2019",K:K)`. This counts the number of times July 31st occurs in my sheet and adds the corresponding K column costs together. I'd like to make this easier on myself and search by month and year only. How can I do this?

Comment: `=SUMIFS(K:K,J:J,">=7/1/19",J:J,"<=7/31/19"`. Or use a pivot table.

Comment: See if the YEAR() and MONTH() function can be used.  e.g. YEAR(cell) & MONTH(cell).